# Return a data frame with all possible pairs/triplets/quadruplets of a value column based on two identifiers, and order the value columns

Tags: performance, sorting, r

Consider the following dummy dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(50)

df <- data.frame(PERSON_ID = sample(1:5, size = 32, replace = TRUE),
                 YEAR = sample(2000:2001, size = 32, replace = TRUE), 
                 VALUES = sample(c("APPLE 50", "GRAPE 20", "ORANGE 50",
                                   "BANANA 80", "TOMATO 100", "PEACH 30",
                                   "CHOCOLATE 90"), size = 32, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% unique()

person_ids <- unique(df$PERSON_ID)
```

The data frame, in reality, is approximately 280,000-300,000 rows. Here is how the dataset looks:

```
df

   PERSON_ID YEAR       VALUES
1          4 2000     APPLE 50
2          3 2001     APPLE 50
3          2 2000     PEACH 30
4          4 2001     APPLE 50
5          3 2000     APPLE 50
6          1 2001 CHOCOLATE 90
7          4 2000    BANANA 80
8          4 2000 CHOCOLATE 90
9          1 2000   TOMATO 100
10         1 2001     APPLE 50
11         2 2000 CHOCOLATE 90
12         2 2000     GRAPE 20
13         4 2000   TOMATO 100
15         2 2001   TOMATO 100
17         5 2001    BANANA 80
18         2 2001     APPLE 50
19         1 2001    ORANGE 50
20         1 2001    BANANA 80
21         4 2001    BANANA 80
22         1 2000     APPLE 50
24         5 2000   TOMATO 100
25         2 2001    BANANA 80
26         4 2001   TOMATO 100
27         3 2001   TOMATO 100
28         2 2000   TOMATO 100
29         2 2001     PEACH 30
31         2 2000     APPLE 50
32         3 2001    ORANGE 50
```

I would like to execute the following code in a more efficient manner, which generates all possible **pairs, triplets, and quadruplets of VALUES** given a **PERSON_ID** and a **YEAR**.

```
generate_value_combinations <- function(df, k){
  for (i in 1:length(person_ids)){
    temp_person_id <- person_ids[i]
    temp <- df %>% filter(PERSON_ID == temp_person_id)
    years <- unique(temp$YEAR)
    years_with_pairs <- 0
    for (j in 1:length(years)){
      temp_year <- temp %>% filter(YEAR == years[j])
      if (nrow(temp_year) >= k){
        years_with_pairs <- years_with_pairs + 1
        temp_year_pairs <- data.frame(t(combn(temp_year$VALUES, m = k)), 
                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        colnames(temp_year_pairs) <- paste0("VALUE_", 1:ncol(temp_year_pairs))
        rm(temp_year)
        temp_year_pairs$YEAR <- years[j]
        temp_year_pairs$PERSON_ID <- person_ids[i]
        if (years_with_pairs == 1){
          temp_year_out <- temp_year_pairs
          rm(temp_year_pairs)
        } else if (years_with_pairs > 1) {
          temp_year_out <- rbind(temp_year_out, temp_year_pairs)
          rm(temp_year_pairs)
        }
      }
    }
    rm(years, temp)

    if (i == 1 & exists("temp_year_out")){
      out <- temp_year_out
      rm(temp_year_out)
    } else if(i > 1 & exists("temp_year_out")) {
      out <- rbind(out, temp_year_out)
      rm(temp_year_out)
    }
    rm(temp_person_id)
  }
  return(out)
}

pairs <- generate_value_combinations(df, k = 2)
triples <- generate_value_combinations(df, k = 3)
quadruplets <- generate_value_combinations(df, k = 4)
```

The code above takes approximately 1-2 hours to execute on the data set of 280,000-300,000 rows.

For example, this is how `pairs` looks:

```
> pairs
        VALUE_1      VALUE_2 YEAR PERSON_ID
1      APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2000         4
2      APPLE 50 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         4
3      APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2000         4
4     BANANA 80 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         4
5     BANANA 80   TOMATO 100 2000         4
6  CHOCOLATE 90   TOMATO 100 2000         4
7      APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         4
8      APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         4
9     BANANA 80   TOMATO 100 2001         4
10     APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         3
11     APPLE 50    ORANGE 50 2001         3
12   TOMATO 100    ORANGE 50 2001         3
13     PEACH 30 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         2
14     PEACH 30     GRAPE 20 2000         2
15     PEACH 30   TOMATO 100 2000         2
16     PEACH 30     APPLE 50 2000         2
17 CHOCOLATE 90     GRAPE 20 2000         2
18 CHOCOLATE 90   TOMATO 100 2000         2
19 CHOCOLATE 90     APPLE 50 2000         2
20     GRAPE 20   TOMATO 100 2000         2
21     GRAPE 20     APPLE 50 2000         2
22   TOMATO 100     APPLE 50 2000         2
23   TOMATO 100     APPLE 50 2001         2
24   TOMATO 100    BANANA 80 2001         2
25   TOMATO 100     PEACH 30 2001         2
26     APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         2
27     APPLE 50     PEACH 30 2001         2
28    BANANA 80     PEACH 30 2001         2
29 CHOCOLATE 90     APPLE 50 2001         1
30 CHOCOLATE 90    ORANGE 50 2001         1
31 CHOCOLATE 90    BANANA 80 2001         1
32     APPLE 50    ORANGE 50 2001         1
33     APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         1
34    ORANGE 50    BANANA 80 2001         1
35   TOMATO 100     APPLE 50 2000         1
```

To make these pairs/triplets/quadruplets consistent among different `PERSON_ID` and `YEAR` combination, we must sort the value columns. The case of pairs has already been covered at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205923/69157:

```
pairs[c('VALUE_1', 'VALUE_2')] <- list(pmin(pairs$VALUE_1, pairs$VALUE_2),
                                       pmax(pairs$VALUE_1, pairs$VALUE_2))

> pairs
        VALUE_1      VALUE_2 YEAR PERSON_ID
1      APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2000         4
2      APPLE 50 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         4
3      APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2000         4
4     BANANA 80 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         4
5     BANANA 80   TOMATO 100 2000         4
6  CHOCOLATE 90   TOMATO 100 2000         4
7      APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         4
8      APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         4
9     BANANA 80   TOMATO 100 2001         4
10     APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         3
11     APPLE 50    ORANGE 50 2001         3
12    ORANGE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         3
13 CHOCOLATE 90     PEACH 30 2000         2
14     GRAPE 20     PEACH 30 2000         2
15     PEACH 30   TOMATO 100 2000         2
16     APPLE 50     PEACH 30 2000         2
17 CHOCOLATE 90     GRAPE 20 2000         2
18 CHOCOLATE 90   TOMATO 100 2000         2
19     APPLE 50 CHOCOLATE 90 2000         2
20     GRAPE 20   TOMATO 100 2000         2
21     APPLE 50     GRAPE 20 2000         2
22     APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2000         2
23     APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2001         2
24    BANANA 80   TOMATO 100 2001         2
25     PEACH 30   TOMATO 100 2001         2
26     APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         2
27     APPLE 50     PEACH 30 2001         2
28    BANANA 80     PEACH 30 2001         2
29     APPLE 50 CHOCOLATE 90 2001         1
30 CHOCOLATE 90    ORANGE 50 2001         1
31    BANANA 80 CHOCOLATE 90 2001         1
32     APPLE 50    ORANGE 50 2001         1
33     APPLE 50    BANANA 80 2001         1
34    BANANA 80    ORANGE 50 2001         1
35     APPLE 50   TOMATO 100 2000         1
```

For triples and quadruplets, we have:

```
sort_df <- function(df){
  value_idx <- max(as.numeric(sub("VALUE_", "", colnames(df)[grepl("VALUE_", colnames(df))])))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (value_idx == 3){
      values <- sort(c(df$VALUE_1[i], df$VALUE_2[i], df$VALUE_3[i]))
    }
    if (value_idx == 4){
      values <- sort(c(df$VALUE_1[i], df$VALUE_2[i], df$VALUE_3[i], df$VALUE_4[i]))
    }
    df$VALUE_1[i] <- values[1]
    df$VALUE_2[i] <- values[2]
    if (value_idx == 3){
      df$VALUE_3[i] <- values[3]
    }
    if (value_idx == 4){
      df$VALUE_4[i] <- values[4]
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
triples <- sort_df(triples)
quadruplets <- sort_df(quadruplets)
```

How can this code be made more efficient?

*Edit*: I would like to mention that I know that "growing" data frames - which I do plenty of here - is considered bad practice in `R`, but I am unaware of how to alternatively code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you know to use `dplyr` is a good start; I'd recommend you read a good tutorial to grasp the important concepts. For example, instead of looping on the PERSON_ID and YEAR, you should use `group_by`. Then, within each PERSON_ID/YEAR, you should apply a same function via `do`. See how the `combn` function from the `utils` package can do a lot of the heavy-lifting:

```
combn(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "B"  "C"  "C"
```

You can wrap it as follows to create a data.frame of pairs, triplets, etc.:

```
combo <- function(x, n) {
  x <- as.data.frame(t(combn(x, n)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(x) <- paste0("VALUES_", 1:n)
  x
}

combo(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)
#   VALUES_1 VALUES_2
# 1        A        B
# 2        A        C
# 3        B        C
```

Putting it all together:

```
pairs <- df %>%
         group_by(PERSON_ID, YEAR) %>%
         filter(n() >= 2) %>%
         do(combo(.$VALUES, 2))

triplets <- df %>%
            group_by(PERSON_ID, YEAR) %>%
            filter(n() >= 3) %>%
            do(combo(.$VALUES, 3))

quadruplets <- df %>%
               group_by(PERSON_ID, YEAR) %>%
               filter(n() >= 4) %>%
               do(combo(.$VALUES, 4))
```

Note that everywhere I used a `filter` step to ensure that `combn` is never called with insufficient data otherwise it will die (e.g. if asking for pairs when there is only one data point).

I hope this will be fast enough on your large data, please let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about `do()`! I had no idea it existed.